# Telerik UI DropDownList not automatically selecting the Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telerik, dropdown

I am using a 'Telerik UI for ASP.NET Core' DropDownList. The datasource is requesting a list of SelectItems where one of the item has the `Selected` value on `true`. My guess is the right behaviour would be for the item to be automatically selected but it is not.

Dropdownlist:

```
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                            .Name("CategoryId")
                            .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("GetQuestionCategories", "Questions").Data("getParentCategoryId")).ServerFiltering(true))
                            .DataValueField("Value")
                            .DataTextField("Text")
                            .Events(events => events.Change("reloadLearningObjectives"))
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control wide-full" })
                )
```

The json text it is requesting:
`[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Algemeen","Value":"62357618-ac53-4092-86d1-6c583b286bbe"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Ballonvaren","Value":"9489c310-7549-45c7-a518-43f8016b2c3b"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Paramotor","Value":"78d1a658-93f1-4eca-8b75-ad4bd4d33ef1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"Part 66","Value":"b7b5845a-e2e0-45be-ad55-002180f8360b"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"ROC-Light","Value":"84ddea95-bda6-46b3-9660-2383d46033a0"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":true,"Text":"Zweefvliegen","Value":"7367e8ff-d4a6-4766-b6b8-59f24f6e7b08"}]`

As you can see the last item has "Selected" to `true` but when the page is done loading it still says that an item needs to be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dataBound event, and set the value of the widget there using the value() method , reference code sample :

https://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-mvc---set-default-value-at-runtime#BV2tUQaLKkaPPOq5WaA9FQ

So you can try to modify above code sample to meet your requirement :

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  // handle the event
 $.each(e.sender.dataSource._data, function (key, value) {
               if(value.Selected==true){
               e.sender.value(value.Value);
               }
            });

},
```